# Why does await function return pending promise

Tags: node.js, async-await

```
let request = require('request-promise')

function get(url) {
  let _opt = {}
  let response = (async () => {
    try {
      var ret = await request(url, _opt);
      return ret;
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e)
    }
  })();
  return response
}

console.log(get('http://www.httpbin.org/ip'))
```

gives:

```
Promise { <pending> }
```

Why doesn't it wait for my response?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why doesn't it wait for my response?

That's simple, **because** you are returning a promise. Node js is single thread and is executed in a non blocking way. 
That means that **return response** in your **get** function is executed before the resolution of *response variable*. 
Try as follow:

```
let request = require('request-promise')

function get(url) {
    let _opt = {}
    return request(url, _opt);
}

async function some () {
    console.log(await get('http://www.httpbin.org/ip'));
}

some();
```

This example is also returning a promise, but in this case we are **awaiting** for the promise resolution. 
Hope this help.

Comment: That's not what I want though. I want the function to return the response. Are you saying this can't be done?

Comment: @pguardiario It can't be done. I strongly suggest you start with callbacks first and learn how to structure your code for async execution before delving into more complicated things like async/await.

Comment: I don't see why though. I can see that the function is blocking, which means that the resource has loaded before the function returns. So why can't I access it directly?

Answer (score 3):

Async functions are non-blocking and will immediately return a promise rather than waiting for a result. This for example, allows for multiple async functions to run concurrently rather than each running sequentially.

To wait for a result, you can use the await keyword to block until the promise is resolved. The await command will return the result of the promise. For example, to log the result of the get function, you can change the last line to:

```
console.log(await get('http://www.httpbin.org/ip'))
```

**UPDATE:**

Let me give this one more try (sorry if I'm beating a dead horse here).

Since your `response` variable is an async function, it's return type is a promise by the definition of an async function. Even though the `ret` variable is await'ed, that just means that it will block while writing to the `ret` variable. The `response` async function needs to be run to completion in order for the await to complete. An await here would be useful if you wanted to wait for the return value and then add post-processing, but in this example specifically, your try block could simply be:

```
try {
    return request(url, _opt)
}
```

Since `request` already returns a promise, the extra await is causing a trivial amount of overhead since it implicitly creates an extra promise.

Since `response` is a promise, and you are returning `response`, the function `get` is also returning a promise. You are then trying to log this promise (which obviously doesn't work). This is why you must `await` or `.then` the `get` function to get the result.

Source: https://medium.com/@bluepnume/learn-about-promises-before-you-start-using-async-await-eb148164a9c8 under "Pitfall 1: not awaiting"

Comment: That's not it. I'm using await and it's not waiting. Also, await can only be used inside an async function.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not the best at javascript (but I've used async-await in C#). Perhaps you could try something like this: get('http://www.httpbin.org/ip').then(response => console.log(response))

Comment: Thanks for trying but this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: I've spent the past hour researching and updated my answer with some information that may be helpful. My apologies if this still doesn't help.

Comment: So then how do I get my code to work without resorting to callbacks?

Comment: @pguardiario There is no possible way. Think about how async functions work carefully. Async/await are just syntax sugar for promises and thus need some sort of callback at some point.